# Groups involving matrices

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices

Let $$H=
  \left\{\left( {\begin{array}{ccc}
   1 & b \\
    0 & 1 \\
  \end{array} } \right)\Bigg\vert b\in \mathbb{R}\right\}$$

How do I show that H is a group and under which operation? I have not done so much with matrices in algebra.
I believe there is a pattern/guide of which I have to follow like when showing subgroups.

Comment: Did you try matrix multiplication as your operation?

Comment: should I prove why I used matrix multiplication?

Comment: no, you can't prove that. You just had to come up with a natural matrix operation for which $H$ is a group, and matrix multiplication does that. You do need to prove that it is a group under matrix multiplication, of course. Check out the nice answers below.

Comment: A "why" cannot be proved. However, it suggests itself to test a set of nosingular matrix for being a *subgroup* of the group (under matrix multiplication) of nonsingular matrices

Comment: To critixize the problem statement: A task to show that a certain set (your $H$ or maybe $A:=\{\text{horse},\text{apple}\}$)- without any reference to a group operation - is a group, makes no sense. Any nonempty set can be equipped with a binary operation that turns it into a group. Hence such a task should always read: Show that the set $X$ with the binary operation $\circ$ is a group. Sometimes, the probelem poser may think that the intended operation is "obvious", but this is simply not the case - as demonstrated by your confusion and question.

Comment: There is an isomorphism between the multiplication of matrices in the $H$ group and addition on the reals.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For $H$ to be a group, $H$ must be closed, satisfy associativity, contain an identity element, and contain an inverse element for each matrix belonging to $H$.

Also, the operation here appears to be *multiplication*.

Let $b,c \in \mathbb{R}$. The set $H$ satisfies **closure** because $$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & b \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & c \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & b+c \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix},$$ where $b+c \in \mathbb{R}$. The product matrix belongs to $H$; hence, $H$ is closed under multiplication.

Also, $H$ satisfies the **associative property**. Matrix multiplication is associative.

There is an **identity element**, or in this case, an identity matrix $$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}.$$

There exists an **inverse element** (in this case, an inverse matrix) in $H$. The inverse matrix is $$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -b \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$ and belongs to $H$ since $-b \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: is it important that I show how I decided to use matrix multiplication instead of addition? That is I define a map and then show equivalence relation?

Comment: If you tried to add matrices, that is, if you thought the operation is addition, then you will be getting $$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & b \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} +\begin{pmatrix} 1 & c \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & b+c \\ 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix}.$$ The closure property is violated here.

Comment: Alright thanks. So then I will not have to go through equivalence relation...

Comment: A detail: Showing that the determinant is nonzero is **not** enough. Nonzero determinant implies that there is an inverse in $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$, which may or may not be in $H$. In this case, just note that $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & -b\\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$ is the inverse of $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & b\\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: @MaxMorin Thanks, yeah that's true. :| I amended my answer to reflect what you pointed out in your comment.

Answer (score 3):

I assume the candidate operations are matrix addition and multiplication.  We can rule out matrix addition since

$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & b \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix} 1 & c \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & b  + c \\ 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix} \notin H; \tag{1}$

$H$ is not closed under matrix addition.  However, we have

$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & b \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & c \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & b + c \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \in H, \tag{2}$

which not only shows $H$ is closed under matrix multiplication, which is in fact associative (as pointed out by dragon), but that

$I = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \tag{3}$

is the identity element for $H$; also, we clearly have

$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & c \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -c \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \in H; \tag{4}$

$H$ contains the multiplicative inverses of all its elements.  So it is indeed an (abelian) group.  Interestingly enough, all these group properties may be read off from (2), without referring them to the space of all matrices, e.g. it is clear from (2) that multiplication must be associative on $H$ etc. etc. etc.